How do I convert a complex Postgres SQL query into a Django queryset?
I have the following SQL query working:
SELECT 
    mrc.token_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(mt.name) AS tracking
FROM 
    markets_rankscurrent mrc
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        mtg.id, 
        mtg.index_id, 
        mtg.favorites_group_id, 
        mtg.name, 
        COALESCE(ufe.token_id, mte.token_id, mie.token_id) AS token_id
    FROM 
        markets_trackinggroup mtg
    LEFT JOIN users_favoritesentry ufe ON mtg.favorites_group_id = ufe.group_id
    LEFT JOIN markets_trackingentry mte ON mtg.id = mte.group_id
    LEFT JOIN markets_indexentry mie ON mtg.index_id = mie.index_id
) mt ON mrc.token_id = mt.token_id
GROUP BY 
    mrc.token_id;

Here are my models:
class Token(models.Model):

class RanksCurrent(models.Model):
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=False)

class TrackingGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Name')
    favorites_group = models.ForeignKey(FavoritesGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tracking_groups', blank=True, null=True)
    index = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tracking_groups', blank=True, null=True)

class TrackingEntry(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(TrackingGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tokens')
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tracking_entries')

class IndexEntry(models.Model):
    index = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='index_tokens')
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='indices')

class FavoritesGroup(models.Model):
    pass

class FavoritesEntry(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(FavoritesGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorites_entries')
    token = models.ForeignKey('markets.Token', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorites_entries')


The TrackingGroup.index foreign key will only be set to a Token object that is also a foreign key in the IndexEntry table.
My end goal is to be able to query the RanksCurrent table and annotate a tracking_groups column that contains a list of TrackingGroup names where the Token is a member. My attempts have made use of Subquery and ArrayAgg to try and do this, but if my subquery returns a list (like I want it to), it fails.
These types of methods have worked for getting the list of TrackingGroup names:
tracking_subquery = TrackingGroup.objects.filter(
    Q(index__index_tokens__token=OuterRef('token_id')) |
    Q(favorites_group__favorites_entries__token=OuterRef('token_id')) |
    Q(tokens__token=OuterRef('token_id'))
).values('name')

tracking_subquery = TrackingGroup.objects.filter(
    Q(favorites_group_id__in=FavoritesEntry.objects.filter(token_id=OuterRef(OuterRef('token_id'))).values('group_id')) |
    Q(id__in=TrackingEntry.objects.filter(token_id=OuterRef(OuterRef('token_id'))).values('group_id')) |
    Q(index_id__in=IndexEntry.objects.filter(token_id=OuterRef(OuterRef('token_id'))).values('index_id'))
).values('name')

However, when I attempt to annotate the main query, it fails:
RanksCurrent.objects.annotate(
    tracking=ArrayAgg(Subquery(tracking_subquery))
)

I thought I would need to move the ArrayAgg call inside the subquery, but that did not make a difference:
RanksCurrent.objects.annotate(
    tracking=Subquery(
        TrackingGroup.objects.filter(
            Q(index__index_tokens__token=OuterRef('token_id')) |
            Q(favorites_group__favorites_entries__token=OuterRef('token_id')) |
            Q(tokens__token=OuterRef('token_id'))
        ).values('name').annotate(group_names=ArrayAgg('name')).values('group_names')))

As far as I can tell, the reason the SQL works is because the inner SELECT statement returns a unique row for each token_id, rather than a row for each TrackingGroup.
My thought right now is to break this up into three separate queries, each targeting one of the *Entry tables, then either somehow combine the resulting lists into a single one and annotate the queryset with it, or just create three separate annotations. I would have already done this if not for getting the operation to work in SQL, so now I want to try and do the same in Django before giving up fully.

Go here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/ and read Executing custom SQL directly.

I am able to execute the query this way and get the data. I tried running the same SQL inside RawSQL like so: RanksCurrent.objects.annotate(tracking=RawSQL(sql, [])) and got the following error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column.

If the query works with cur.execute() just use that. Life is too short to fight the Django ORM.

I wasn't sure how to merge the resulting array back into the queryset, although I admittedly did not spend a ton of time thinking about it. At the moment I have settled for annotating three separate queries and combining them in the serializer. Hopefully the time penalty isn't too bad as a result.

Why  do you care if it is a queryset, just use the values from  cur.fetch*().

Mainly because I already had a serializer set up to streamline the conversion process and if it integrated cleanly then I wouldn't need to do it manually elsewhere. The rest of the model has its own complexities and I want to minimize additional ones where I can.

My current solution is to perform three separate queries and merge them in the serializer:
tracking_index_groups_subquery = Subquery(
    queryset_filtered.filter(
        token__indices__index__tracking_groups__isnull=False,
        id=OuterRef('id')
    ).values('id').annotate(
        index_tracking=ArrayAgg('token__indices__index__tracking_groups__name')
    ).values('index_tracking')[:1]
)

tracking_favorites_groups_subquery = Subquery(
    queryset_filtered.filter(
        token__favorites_entries__group__tracking_groups__isnull=False,
        id=OuterRef('id')
    ).values('id').annotate(
        favorites_tracking=ArrayAgg('token__favorites_entries__group__tracking_groups__name')
    ).values('favorites_tracking')[:1]
)

tracking_groups_subquery = Subquery(
    queryset_filtered.filter(
        token__tracking_entries__group__isnull=False,
        id=OuterRef('id')
    ).values('id').annotate(
        tracking=ArrayAgg('token__tracking_entries__group__name')
    ).values('tracking')[:1]
)

queryset_filtered = queryset_filtered.annotate(
    index_tracking=tracking_index_groups_subquery,
    favorites_tracking=tracking_favorites_groups_subquery,
    tracking=tracking_groups_subquery
)


class RanksCurrentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracking = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tracking')

    def get_tracking(self, obj):
        tracking = []
        if obj.index_tracking:
            tracking.extend(obj.index_tracking)
        if obj.favorites_tracking:
            tracking.extend(obj.favorites_tracking)
        if obj.tracking:
            tracking.extend(obj.tracking)
        return tracking

